# QWebEnginePage printToPdf only print part of page

Tags: qt, qtwebengine, qt5.7

I use `QWebEnginePage.printToPdf` method to print the web which render by the QWebEnginePage in Qt 5.7. But the method only present one part of the web.

The code as below:

```
webEngineView->page()->printToPdf(pdfPath, 
   QPageLayout(QPageSize(QPageSize::A4), QPageLayout::Portrait, QMarginsF()));
```

What's the problem?

Comment: Did you find the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You should change the QPageSize to a larger one, for example A3. It worked in my app.

I use PyQt5.8 and Qt5.8.

This is my python code:

```
    ps = QPageSize(QPageSize.A3)
    pl = QPageLayout(ps, QPageLayout.Portrait, QMarginsF())
    self.webpage.printToPdf(pdfPath, pageLayout=pl)
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the issue is not related to css on the page. If you have set the html/body height to 100%, then effectively the printable area is limited to the viewable area.